# Sublimits of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble finding the sublimits of the sequence:

$b_n= a_n + {n!}^{-1/n}$

$a_n$ is a sequence defined as:

$a_1=1$ $a_{n+1}=2 \sqrt{a_n} +1 $

(I already proved that $a_n$ is crescent and convergent)

I tried to use the even and odd terms but I don't think it's the right way to do it... How can I find the sublimits of this sequence?

Comment: $\lim n!^{-1/n}=0$, so it seems that $\lim b_n=\lim a_n$.

Comment: ...And that $\lim a_n=3+2\sqrt2$.

Comment: It can be either that or $3 - 2\sqrt2$

Comment: Why do you say the limit zero?